# Any way to ignore stdClass Object in xml file?

Tags: php, xml

I want to ignore "stdClass Object
(" and the last ")" in the XML file. Am I fetching the xml file with request wrong?

Creating a xml file by Soap request:

```
$soap = new \SoapClient($request, $options);
        $res = $soap->ExecuteQuery(['query' => $xmlQuery]);
        $fileOpen = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..') . '/xmlFile.xml';
        $fil = fopen($fileOpen, "a");
        fwrite($fil, print_r($res, true));
        fclose($fil);
```

The created xmlFile.xml:

```
stdClass Object
(
[ExecuteQueryResult] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data totalExecutionTime="00:00:13.1123107">
<Product id="84650" ... >
...
</Product>
</Data>
)
```

Trying to use this to read the xml-file:

```
$xml1 = new \XMLReader();
$xml1->open(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..') . '/xmlFile.xml');
```

I end up getting this error:

```
Warning: XMLReader::open() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given on 
"$xml1->open(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..') . '/xmlFile.xml');"
```

Comment: `var_dump($res)` please

Comment: var_dumped: "object(stdClass)#23679 (1) { ["ExecuteQueryResult"]=> string(60653929) " KLdji392...." @delboy1978uk

Comment: exactlty as above then

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP returns stdClass objects. Based on the `var_dump()`, it looks like you need to access the `ExecuteQueryResult` property in order to get the XML string.

Therefore, give this a try:

```
$xml = $res->ExecuteQueryResult;
fwrite($fil, $xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fwrite($fil, $res->ExecuteQueryResult);
```

`$soap->ExecuteQuery` returns an object, you're only interested in the `ExecuteQueryResult` field.